# How to write separate log file for each instance of a class?

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging, filehandler

I am using java.util.logging for logging my program, the problem is that I need to create separate log file for each instance of class test case. For example, I have three test case objects, and in the end I get three log files, but:

Test Case #3 contains log for test case #3, Test Case #2 contains logs for test cases 2 and 3, and test case #1 contains log of all test cases.

Here is my code:

```
public class TestCase {
    TestCase(String tcName){
        this.tcName = tcName;
    }

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger("com.sigmaukraine.trn.autotest.testcase");
    String tcName;
    String scenarioReportDir;
    List<Keyword> kwList = new ArrayList<Keyword>();

public void executeTestCase(){
            //saving log for current test case
            try {
                FileHandler fh;
                String fileName = new StringBuilder(tcName).append(".log").toString();
                // This block configure the logger with handler and formatter
                fh = new FileHandler(scenarioReportDir + fileName);
                log.addHandler(fh);
                SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
                fh.setFormatter(formatter);
                log.info("Executing test case: " + tcName);

            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for(Keyword k : kwList){
                k.executeKeyword();
            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is in

```
log.addHandler(fh);
```

its keep on adding the handler. so the behavior is as you are seeing. You should use

```
fh.close();
log.removeHandler(fh);
```

after executing test case.

Comment: thanks, now it works, but temporary .lck files have left in the directory

Comment: close handler before removing.

Answer (score -3):

```
<appender name="RootSiftAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.sift.SiftingAppender">
      <discriminator>
         <Key><strong>testname</strong></Key>
         <DefaultValue><strong>testrun</strong></DefaultValue>
      </discriminator>
      <sift>
         <appender name="FILE-${testname}" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
            <File>${testname}.log</File>
            <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
               <FileNamePattern><strong>${testname}.%i.log</strong></FileNamePattern>
               <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
               <MaxIndex>100</MaxIndex>
            </rollingPolicy>
            <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
               <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
            </triggeringPolicy>
            <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
               <Pattern>%d{ISO8601} %-5level %C{1} [%M:%L] [%thread] - %msg%n</Pattern>
            </layout>
         </appender>
      </sift>
   </appender>
```

Comment: The OP is asking about `java.util.logging` not `slf4j-logback`.